# How to group large stream into sub streams

Tags: scala, fs2

I want to group large `Stream[F, A]` into  `Stream[Stream[F, A]]` with at most `n` element for inner stream.

This is what I did, basically pipe chunks into `Queue[F, Queue[F, Chunk[A]]`, and then yields queue elements as result stream.

```
 implicit class StreamSyntax[F[_], A](s: Stream[F, A])(
    implicit F: Concurrent[F]) {

    def groupedPipe(
      lastQRef: Ref[F, Queue[F, Option[Chunk[A]]]],
      n: Int): Pipe[F, A, Stream[F, A]] = { in =>
      val initQs =
        Queue.unbounded[F, Option[Queue[F, Option[Chunk[A]]]]].flatMap { qq =>
          Queue.bounded[F, Option[Chunk[A]]](1).flatMap { q =>
            lastQRef.set(q) *> qq.enqueue1(Some(q)).as(qq -> q)
          }
        }

      Stream.eval(initQs).flatMap {
        case (qq, initQ) =>
          def newQueue = Queue.bounded[F, Option[Chunk[A]]](1).flatMap { q =>
            qq.enqueue1(Some(q)) *> lastQRef.set(q).as(q)
          }

          val evalStream = {
            in.chunks
              .evalMapAccumulate((0, initQ)) {
                case ((i, q), c) if i + c.size >= n =>
                  val (l, r) = c.splitAt(n - i)
                  q.enqueue1(Some(l)) >> q.enqueue1(None) >> q
                    .enqueue1(None) >> newQueue.flatMap { nq =>
                    nq.enqueue1(Some(r)).as(((r.size, nq), c))
                  }
                case ((i, q), c) if (i + c.size) < n =>
                  q.enqueue1(Some(c)).as(((i + c.size, q), c))
              }
              .attempt ++ Stream.eval {
              lastQRef.get.flatMap { last =>
                last.enqueue1(None) *> last.enqueue1(None)
              } *> qq.enqueue1(None)
            }
          }
          qq.dequeue.unNoneTerminate
            .map(
              q =>
                q.dequeue.unNoneTerminate
                  .flatMap(Stream.chunk)
                  .onFinalize(
                    q.dequeueChunk(Int.MaxValue).unNoneTerminate.compile.drain))
            .concurrently(evalStream)
      }
    }

    def grouped(n: Int) = {
      Stream.eval {
        Queue.unbounded[F, Option[Chunk[A]]].flatMap { empty =>
          Ref.of[F, Queue[F, Option[Chunk[A]]]](empty)
        }
      }.flatMap { ref =>
        val p = groupedPipe(ref, n)
        s.through(p)
      }
    }
  }
```

But it is very complicated, is there any simpler way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use a more reliable version (use Hotswap ensure queue termination) like this.

```
  def grouped(
      innerSize: Int
    )(implicit F: Async[F]): Stream[F, Stream[F, A]] = {

      type InnerQueue = Queue[F, Option[Chunk[A]]]
      type OuterQueue = Queue[F, Option[InnerQueue]]

      def swapperInner(swapper: Hotswap[F, InnerQueue], outer: OuterQueue) = {
        val innerRes =
          Resource.make(Queue.unbounded[F, Option[Chunk[A]]])(_.offer(None))
        swapper.swap(innerRes).flatTap(q => outer.offer(q.some))
      }

      def loopChunk(
        gathered: Int,
        curr: Queue[F, Option[Chunk[A]]],
        chunk: Chunk[A],
        newInnerQueue: F[InnerQueue]
      ): F[(Int, Queue[F, Option[Chunk[A]]])] = {
        if (gathered + chunk.size > innerSize) {
          val (left, right) = chunk.splitAt(innerSize - gathered)
          curr.offer(left.some) >> newInnerQueue.flatMap { nq =>
            loopChunk(0, nq, right, newInnerQueue)
          }
        } else if (gathered + chunk.size == innerSize) {
          curr.offer(chunk.some) >> newInnerQueue.tupleLeft(
            0
          )
        } else {
          curr.offer(chunk.some).as(gathered + chunk.size -> curr)
        }
      }

      val prepare = for {
        outer   <- Resource.eval(Queue.unbounded[F, Option[InnerQueue]])
        swapper <- Hotswap.create[F, InnerQueue]
      } yield outer -> swapper

      Stream.resource(prepare).flatMap {
        case (outer, swapper) =>
          val newInner = swapperInner(swapper, outer)
          val background = Stream.eval(newInner).flatMap { initQueue =>
            s.chunks
              .filter(_.nonEmpty)
              .evalMapAccumulate(0 -> initQueue) { (state, chunk) =>
                val (gathered, curr) = state
                loopChunk(gathered, curr, chunk, newInner).tupleRight({})
              }
              .onFinalize(swapper.clear *> outer.offer(None))
          }
          val foreground = Stream
            .fromQueueNoneTerminated(outer)
            .map(i => Stream.fromQueueNoneTerminatedChunk(i))
          foreground.concurrently(background)
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

fs2 has [`chunkN`](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/blob/series/1.0/core/shared/src/main/scala/fs2/Stream.scala#L337) [`chunkLimit`](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/blob/series/1.0/core/shared/src/main/scala/fs2/Stream.scala#L318) methods that can help with grouping

```
stream.chunkN(n).map(Stream.chunk)

stream.chunkLimit(n).map(Stream.chunk)
```

`chunkN` produces chunks of size n until the end of a stream

`chunkLimit` splits existing chunks and can produce chunks with variable size.

```
scala> Stream(1,2,3).repeat.chunkN(2).take(5).toList
res0: List[Chunk[Int]] = List(Chunk(1, 2), Chunk(3, 1), Chunk(2, 3), Chunk(1, 2), Chunk(3, 1))

scala> (Stream(1) ++ Stream(2, 3) ++ Stream(4, 5, 6)).chunkLimit(2).toList
res0: List[Chunk[Int]] = List(Chunk(1), Chunk(2, 3), Chunk(4, 5), Chunk(6))
```

Comment: Yes, but that group data inti `Chunk` instead of `Stream`

Comment: Yes, it produces chunks. Fortunately Stream.chunk method can easily create stream from a chunk if you need

Comment: Probably I misunderstood you first time. My suggestion is produces stream of strict chunks but you need stream of lazy streams. I guess it is not easy because to start new substream you need to know where previous one ended. So previous substream  should be evaluated already, meaning all the chunks are strict.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the already mentioned `chunksN`, also consider using [`groupWithin`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/co/fs2/fs2-core_2.12/1.0.1/fs2-core_2.12-1.0.1-javadoc.jar/!/fs2/Stream.html#groupWithin%5BF2%5Bx%5D%3E:F%5Bx%5D%5D(n:Int,d:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration)(implicittimer:cats.effect.Timer%5BF2%5D,implicitF:cats.effect.Concurrent%5BF2%5D):fs2.Stream%5BF2,fs2.Chunk%5BO%5D%5D) (fs2 1.0.1):

> `def groupWithin[F2[x] >: F[x]](n: Int, d: FiniteDuration)(implicit timer: Timer[F2], F: Concurrent[F2]): Stream[F2, Chunk[O]]`
>
> Divide this streams into groups of elements received within a time window, or limited by the number of the elements, whichever happens first. Empty groups, which can occur if no elements can be pulled from upstream in a given time window, will not be emitted.
>
> Note: a time window starts each time downstream pulls.

I'm not sure why you'd want this to be nested streams, since the requirement is to have "at most `n` elements" in one batch - which implies that you're keeping track of a finite number of elements (which is exactly what a `Chunk` is for). Either way, a `Chunk` can always be represented as a `Stream` with `Stream.chunk`:

```
val chunks: Stream[F, Chunk[O]] = ???
val streamOfStreams:  Stream[F, Stream[F, O]] = chunks.map(Stream.chunk)
```

Here's a complete example of how to use `groupWithin`:

```
import cats.implicits._
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp}
import fs2._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object GroupingDemo extends IOApp {
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    Stream('a, 'b, 'c).covary[IO]
      .groupWithin(2, 1.second)
      .map(_.toList)
      .showLinesStdOut
      .compile.drain
      .as(ExitCode.Success)
  }
}
```

Outputs:

> List('a, 'b)
>
> List('c)