# Grouping a stream of elements into multiple streams

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, fs2

Let's say we have a `case class MyCaseClass(name: String, value: Int)`. Given an `fs2.Stream[F, MyCaseClass]` I want to group elements with the same `name`

```
val sourceStream: fs2.Stream[F, MyCaseClass] = //
val groupedSameNameStream: fs2.Stream[F, fs2.Stream[F, MyCaseClass]] = //
```

The reason I need to do this is I want to apply effectfful transformation

```
val transform: MyCaseClass => F[Unit] = //
```

to all elements of a stream and in case one group fails the other should keep working.

Is something like this possible to do?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "keep working" ? Can you also give an example how you want to apply this transformation to `groupedSameNameStream`?

Comment: It looks that you want some kind of aggregation on "life" stream, but it's not that simple as it may look like at first glance. Spark, for example, is doing a lot of magic with watermarks to make it works. I don't think fs2 can handle such sophisticated cases.

Comment: After some investigation I found that it can handle something like this using `groupWithin`, but you wont get groups of streams. There will be `groups of elements received within a time window, or limited by the number of the elements`.

Comment: Seems a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52942137/how-to-group-large-stream-into-sub-streams

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko I'm not sure if it's the case since in my case `Stream`s are infinte while `Chunk` is finite by definition. The solution using for splitting that I googled is using `Queue`, but it's unclear how to adapt it for possibly infinite stream of streams.

Comment: @SomeName I don't think it is possible in general (not because of fs2 limitation). let's say at time `N` you source stream received words `aa`, `bb`, `aa`. And you wand to group by these words. In this case at time `N` you grouped stream would have two groups  (one per `aa` and one per `bb`)  that can be consumed by any consumer. But what if after the consumption of group `aa` there will be another `aa` word in a source stream. Should it be a new group with only one element? Or should it be ignored because group with `aa` has already been consumed.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, with caveats.

It's *relatively* straightforward to do this if you accept having a `Map` with an unbounded number of keys, and an unbounded number of associated `Queue`s for each.

We've use code based on a [gist by github user kiambogo](https://gist.github.com/kiambogo/8247a7bbf79f00414d1489b7e6fc90d0) in production (though ours has been tweaked), and it works fine:

```
import fs2.concurrent.Queue
import cats.implicits._
import cats.effect.Concurrent
import cats.effect.concurrent.Ref
 
def groupBy[F[_], A, K](selector: A => F[K])(implicit F: Concurrent[F]): Pipe[F, A, (K, Stream[F, A])] = {
  in =>
  Stream.eval(Ref.of[F, Map[K, Queue[F, Option[A]]]](Map.empty)).flatMap { st =>
    val cleanup = {
      import alleycats.std.all._
      st.get.flatMap(_.traverse_(_.enqueue1(None)))
    }

    (in ++ Stream.eval_(cleanup))
      .evalMap { el =>
        (selector(el), st.get).mapN { (key, queues) =>
          queues.get(key).fold {
            for {
              newQ <- Queue.unbounded[F, Option[A]] // Create a new queue
              _ <- st.modify(x => (x + (key -> newQ), x)) // Update the ref of queues
              _ <- newQ.enqueue1(el.some)
            } yield (key -> newQ.dequeue.unNoneTerminate).some
          }(_.enqueue1(el.some) as None)
        }.flatten
      }.unNone.onFinalize(cleanup)
  }
}
```

If we assume an overhead of 64 bytes for each Map entry (I believe this is *very* overestimated) then a cardinality of 100,000 unique keys gives us approximately 6.1MiB - *well* within reasonable size for a jvm process.

Comment: Curious why the selector needs to be a return in F? Why `A => F[K]` and not `A => K`?